# Sorting cells in UITableView into sections, after TableView has been loaded

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Right, so my UITableView loads and puts all the cells in Alphabetical order. Information is then downloaded from a server and calculations are done, with the TableView being reloaded once everything is complete. Currently this is quite a simple procedure as once the information is downloaded from the server, the cells don't even move, they are left in their alphabetical order. Nothing really happens other than half of the information is filled in and small changes are made depending on the calculations. I was wondering if there was an easy way of putting the cells into sections depending on the calculations done after the download is complete? I did have an idea of creating 4 arrays (there will only be 4 sections ever) and once isLoading is set to no, changing the data source of the TableView to have sections, however, that sounds a bit... iffy. I know this is a theoretical question as opposed to a coding problem, but before I go and mess up my code, in what is sure to be a stupidly inefficient way of doing things, is there an easy way of "assigning" UITableViewCells to sections?

My main issue with my way of doing it is that should the user delete a cell, deleting the appropriate entry in Core Data will be a little tricky and prone to errors. This lead me on to another idea. What if I added an extra attribute to my Core Data entity. That attribute would be assigned and then saved once the calculations were done. The problem with this is that no existing databases would work. There has to be a neat way of achieving this.

Thanks for the help. If you need me to post any code just say so and I will.

Comment: Can you clarify the problem related to adding an attribute in Core Data and having DB problems after?

Comment: @Bill Well, my app has already been distributed somewhat. Adding a another attribute will cause incompatibility with anyone who has used the app, meaning they'd have to reinstall the app, am I correct?

Comment: In that sense, yes. Ideally you can version your API to your DB so that updates won't cause a problem.

Comment: @Bill Pretty sure that would be beyond me!

Comment: Sounds complicated but could be just passing an extra key that specifies a version when initiating the connection to your DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be fine if you implement the data source methods related to sections.

For example:

- numberOfSectionsInTableView
- sectionIndexTitlesForTableView.

Any time the table data is reloaded (e.g., [self.tableView reloadData]), these methods will be called and the data will be placed into their sections.

Keep in mind that the cells are just the visual representation of your model, which in this case is your fetched data. The cells are not assigned to sections; they are simply created however you specify for your model (via the table view data source and delegate methods).

Regarding deletion of entries while using Core Data, I suggest taking a look at [NSFetchedResultsController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html). The latter will monitor any changes to your table's data and message its delegate, your table view controller, when updates are made.

For example, a deletion would start with a call to the table view delegate like normal (i.e., via tableView:didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath). Within the latter, you would then delete the entry from core data (e.g., [self.myDatabase.managedObjectContext deleteObject:entity]). Assuming you initiated the NSFetchedResultsController w/ the same managed object context, the deletion would be automatically reflected back to your user.

If you're using a remote DB, however, you'll also have to perform a save (however you've implemented that) to ensure the DB is updated too.

Note also that if you use an NSFetchedResultsController, you don't need to implement the section data source methods since NSFetchedResultsController can handle that for you. Just define the key-path in your data model that will return the section name when initializing the NSFetchedResultsController.

Comment: Thanks Bill! I'm currently using NSFetchedResultsController, does it take into account sections? i.e. Something in section 2 position 1, may actually be the first entry loaded from the core data. If deleted would this still delete the correct entry, or is NSFetchedResultsController a dumb method?

Comment: Yes, the NSFetchedResultsController accepts an optional key-path to return the section name. Take a look at this [reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Specifically, initWithFetchRequest:managedObjectContext:sectionNameKeyPath:cacheName.

Comment: Thanks again Bill. Having another think about it now. I'm already using NSFRC, but from what I can tell, there's no way of using NSFRC to achieve what I want without making another attribute to my entity. Am I right? In which case I'd have to do it through the TableView delegate meaning deletion from Core Data would be trickier. If I've got this wrong, please say so. I'm pretty new to all this stuff!

Comment: Np. The deletion is a mix of stuff. Editing above.

Comment: Hmmm. Thank you Bill. I think I'm being a bit of an idiot and just need to think about this for a while. I'm going to mark your solution as correct and if I still don't know where to go, I'll post a separate question which will be more specific thanks to this starting point. You've been absolutely fantastic, and I really appreciate your effort.